# Dialogflow issue related to enum entity

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have created entity for size and it is not working as expected. below is my size entity

[image]

[image]
[image]

and my price entity

[image]

i have intent for search. So when i say **search camera in 200 dollar** it give me response as below [image]

but when i do same search with size entity like this **search camera in 23 megapixel** it does not recognize **23 megapixel** as size. Please help me how can i resolve this issue.

As i have noticed when i train my agent with user says as **"i want camera for 20 megapixel"** and when i test it in console with phrase **"i need camera in 20 megapixel"** in this case it only recognize **camera** [i have separate entity for camera]

But when i do same search with phrase as **i need camera in 200 dollars"**
it works. It seems it does not recognize my **size** entity because of different text variance.

As i tested more my agent only recognize size entity when my phrases matches with phrase that i have used in training phrases.